# Get get actual resolution of largest photo

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any way to retrieve the actual resolution of the largest version of a facebook photo from the graph api or FQL without having to download the image to the browser/server?

It looks like it should be easy using the graph api but when you inspect the JSON closer it's actually not. The way that the graph api returns width and height doesn't seem to make sense. In the example below if you view the 2048px photo you can see that it's actually only 731px wide. The "source" width and height of 720px also aren't accurate. 720px isn't that different then 731, but with other larger images they're still listed as 720px there.

In terms of fql, you can retrieve src_big,src_big_height,src_big_width but this seems to only return the 720px version of the photo even though facebook may actually save a larger version (it says up to 960px but I've seen up to the full 2048)

I'm assuming facebook has a reason for doing it this way, but for my purposes (and I'm sure other people's) it would be useful to get the actual width and height of images.

```
{
  "id": "10151509108346729", 
  "picture": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/68051_10151509108346729_1731694342_s.png", 
  "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/68051_10151509108346729_1731694342_n.png", 
  "height": 720, 
  "width": 720, 
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 2048, 
      "width": 2048, 
      "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s2048x2048/68051_10151509108346729_1731694342_n.png"
...
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved Sabrina?

Comment: Yes, Facebook fixed this issue.